# vue animate child component to view and then route to it without destroying/remounting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, vue-router

I am at a loss about this problem I am facing and I can't seem to find similar problems online. I am using Vue 3 and Vue router.

I want to create the following: I have a page with cards and whenever a card gets clicked, it animates to full screen. For the more visually minded, the Apple App Store has a similar effect and also this dutch website in desktop view: https://aboutcoolblue.com/nl/

This website animates the card into view and then also updates the url. I want this too (this way you can also browse to that view without the main page), but when I animate the card to full screen using JS and then push the router to the component, the page flashes and upon further inspection creates a new component/the original component is destroyed.

To me it is not clear what makes a component stay alive or recreated. Online I can find a lot of people who want to destroy the component, but that is not what I want because I do not want the flash.

These are the culprits I can think of:
Of course on the main page, I need to supply the card data using props, whereas when the card is in main view, it needs to get this from the route params.

Furthermore at the end of the js animation, some DOM elements have different styling than the component would have in main view (i.e. fixed vs relative position).

Can anyone help me with a strategy to make this work?

This is the card component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
// removed imports for conciseness

const props = defineProps<{
  slug?: string;
  closed?: boolean;
}>();

onMounted(async () => {
  const url = route.params.slug ? route.params.slug : props.slug;

  const data: any = await auth.get("/content/" + url);
  if (data) {
    cardContent.value = data.data;
  }

  $(window).on("scroll", () => {
    // irrelevant scroll behaviour
  });
});

onUnmounted(() => {
  $(window).off("scroll");
});

const openCard = (e: Event) => {
  if (!props.closed) {
    return;
  }

  const SPEED = 500;


  // clone the card to fixed pos & set transition durations
  // ...

  setTimeout(() => {
    // set destination values
    // ... animation runs

    // route to the card view !! this works but component is destroyed and recreated
    setTimeout(() => {
      router.push("card/" + cardContent.value.slug);
    }, SPEED + 1);
  }, 1);
};
</script>
```

This is the main page that contains the card component as a child:

```
import { ref, reactive, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useAuthStore } from "../store/auth";

import Card from "./Card.vue";

const state = reactive({
  content: null
});

onMounted(async () => {
  const data: any = await auth.get("/content/");
  state.content = data.data.results[0];
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
        <Card
          class="overflow-hidden rounded-3xl"
          v-if="state.content"
          :closed="true"
          :slug="state.content.slug"
        ></Card>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is App.vue

```
import { defineComponent, KeepAlive } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({});
</script>

<template>
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <keep-alive>
      <component :is="Component" />
    </keep-alive>
  </router-view>
</template>
```

these are the relevant routes in main.ts

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/card/:slug', component: Card },
];
```